# Gitlab cached wrong gem package on CI

Tags: rubygems, gitlab-ci

I have a custom rubygems server, where some custom gems are published. I've created a new gem, let's call it `the_gem`. And published it with a version of `1.0.0`. Another project (main project) under my gitlab uses that gem, so I've included it there. Then, CI on main_project started. It fetched the 1.0.0 version of the gem using `bundle install --path /tmp/bundle` command. Then, I realized I've made a mistake in `the_gem`, so I've fixed it with a still version `1.0.0`, since the gem isn't used anywhere yet.

I ran CI on my main project once again, and instead of fetching gem from my server, it used somewhere cached first version (`using the_gem 1.0.0` instead of expected `installing the_gem 1.0.0 from my.cusomgems.com`.

I strongly believe Gitlab cached the gem somewhere to speedup CI time.

But is there any way to delete the gem from gitlab, wherever it stores it, to download the updated package again?

P.S. I know there is a `simple` way - to release `1.0.1` version, but I would like to avoid that if it's possible, and stick with the version 1.0.0.

Comment: What kind of runner executor (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) are you using? e.g. Docker, Shell, SSH?

Comment: I'm using `docker`

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab actually isn't the issue here. Rubygems doesn't allow overwriting a gem version. You can use `gem yank` to remove a bad release, but you won't be able to publish another `1.0.0` on that server. More information can be found in this [github comment](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/992#issuecomment-52476103).